# Displaying large TextViews efficiently in Android DialogFragments

Tags: android, textview, android-dialogfragment

I am attempting to show some licensing information for my Android application using a DialogFragment that contains a TextView wrapped inside of a ScrollView. In specific I am using the String generated from the GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo() method. The String generated here contains a large amount of text and when I pass the required information to the Dialog to be displayed the UI thread freezes for about 3-4 seconds before finally showing the dialog. Is there a more efficient way to display large amounts of text within a DialogFragment?

Here is the code where the Dialog is instantiated and shown.

```
if(googlePlayServicesLicense != null) {

   // Google Play Service License Info
    TitleParagraphViewModel googlePlayInfo = 
    new TitleParagraphViewModel("Google Play Services", 
    googlePlayServicesLicense);

    infoList.add(googlePlayInfo);
}

// Create license dialog and show
TitleParagraphListDialog dialog = 
TitleParagraphListDialog.newInstance("Licenses", infoList);

// Show the dialog
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Here is the code for my DialogFragment

```
public class TitleParagraphListDialog extends DialogFragment {
private static final String DIALOG_TITLE_EXTRA_KEY = "dialog_title";
private static final String DIALOG_INFO_LIST_EXTRA_KEY = "info_list";
private String mDialogTitle;
private ArrayList<TitleParagraphViewModel> mInfoList;
private TextView mInformation;

public static TitleParagraphListDialog newInstance(String title, ArrayList<TitleParagraphViewModel> infoList) {
    TitleParagraphListDialog dialog = new TitleParagraphListDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(DIALOG_TITLE_EXTRA_KEY, title);
    args.putParcelableArrayList(DIALOG_INFO_LIST_EXTRA_KEY, infoList);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    mDialogTitle = args.getString(DIALOG_TITLE_EXTRA_KEY) != null ? args.getString(DIALOG_TITLE_EXTRA_KEY) : "Information";
    mInfoList = (ArrayList<TitleParagraphViewModel>) (args.getParcelableArrayList(DIALOG_INFO_LIST_EXTRA_KEY) != null ? args.getParcelableArrayList(DIALOG_INFO_LIST_EXTRA_KEY) : new ArrayList<TitleParagraphViewModel>());
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.title_paragraph_dialog, null);
    TextView dialogTitle = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
    mInformation = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.information);

    dialogTitle.setText(mDialogTitle);

    dialogTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
            .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"));

    mInformation.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity()
            .getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"));

    for(TitleParagraphViewModel info : mInfoList) {
        mInformation.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + info.getTitle() + "</b>")
                + "\n\n" + info.getParagraph() + "\n\n");
    }

    builder.setView(dialogView)
    .setPositiveButton("Done", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            TitleParagraphListDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

I would like to know a better way to handle displaying large amounts of text. I tried using a ListView but performance was worse. The GooglePlayServices license is just one of many licenses that I may need to display in my app.

If you are wondering about the TitleParagraphViewModel here is the code for it.

```
public class TitleParagraphViewModel implements Parcelable {
private String title, paragraph;

public TitleParagraphViewModel(String title, String paragraph) {
    this.title = title;
    this.paragraph = paragraph;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setParagraph(String paragraph) {
    this.paragraph = paragraph;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}

public String getParagraph() {
    return this.paragraph;
}

// Parceling Part
public TitleParagraphViewModel(Parcel in) {
    readFromParcel(in);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.getTitle(), this.getParagraph()});
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    String[] stringData = new String[2];
    in.readStringArray(stringData);
    this.setTitle(stringData[0]);
    this.setParagraph(stringData[1]);
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    @Override
    public Object createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new TitleParagraphViewModel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Object[size];
    }

};
}
```

Comment: [getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(android.content.Context)) is now deprecated. Apps no longer have to display this information.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up splitting the long text into an array of individual lines and then used [appcompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview)'s [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) to display that array of lines.

Here's the code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;

public class GoogleLicenseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_close, null);

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        String licenseInfo = googleApiAvailability.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(activity);

        if (licenseInfo != null) {
            Context context = getDialogContext(activity);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = createRecyclerView(context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new LongMessageAdapter(context, licenseInfo));
            builder.setView(recyclerView);
        }

        return builder.create();
    }

    private Context getDialogContext(Context context) {
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        int resId = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.dialogTheme;
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(resId, outValue, true);
        int themeId = outValue.resourceId;
        return themeId == 0 ? context : new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeId);
    }

    private RecyclerView createRecyclerView(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_dialog, null);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

        return recyclerView;
    }

    private static final class LongMessageAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        private final Context context;
        private final String[] lines;

        public LongMessageAdapter(Context context, String message) {
            this.context = context;
            this.lines = message.split("\\n");
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return lines.length;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.TextAppearance_AppCompat_Subhead);
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView) {
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ((TextView) holder.itemView).setText(lines[position]);
        }
    }
}
```

recycler_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingRight="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/abc_dialog_padding_top_material"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to initialize some kind of progress bar or some "please wait" dialog, then immediately after start an asynctask thread and retrieve the text on doInBackground.

that way you avoid doing long calls on the UI thread and your app wont freeze.
then use onPostExecute of that asynctask to remove the "please wait" dialog (or whatever you choose to use) and show the text.

Another idea is to call only a few lines in the scrollbar, and load more as the user scrolls down.

sorry if a only answered with ideas, hope it can enlighten something for you.